# How to take input in SEQUENCE lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sequence

I am trying to write a sorting code in lisp language.
But I am not sure how to do it.
I want to use sort function of lisp using sequence.
I am trying to create sequence like this-

```
(setq arr (make-sequence '(vector integer) 10   :initial-element (read)))
(terpri)
(write arr)
```

This will set the initial element to user input. But I want to take input from the user and I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make vectors with [`MAKE-ARRAY`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ar.htm). You can set its fill-pointer to 0, and then use a loop to add 10 numbers to it with [`VECTOR-PUSH`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_vec_ps.htm):

```
(let ((vec (make-array 10 :fill-pointer 0)))
  (dotimes (i 10 vec)
    (format *query-io* "Number ~d/10: " (1+ i))
    (finish-output *query-io*)
    (vector-push (parse-integer (read-line *query-io*)) vec)))
```

You could also achieve the same like this:

```
(make-array 10 :initial-contents
            (loop
               for i from 1 to 10
               do (format *query-io* "Number ~d/10: " i)
               do (finish-output *query-io*)
               collecting (parse-integer (read-line *query-io*))))
```

But that creates a temporary list for the input.

Also, as Svante suggested, you can use `MAP-INTO`:

```
;; If you don't want the number in the prompt, you can remove the LET
(let ((i 0))
  (map-into (make-array 10)
            (lambda () 
              (format *query-io* "Number ~d/10: " (incf i))
              (finish-output *query-io*)
              (parse-integer (read-line *query-io*)))))
```

Comment: remember that you need FINISH-OUTPUT if you want I/O to reach the user. Some I/O system might be buffered.

Comment: You can also use `map-into` instead of a fill pointer and `vector-push`.